# Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am currently upgrading angular 4 to angular 6 code. I have installed "rxjs": "^6.3.2" and un-installed rxjs-compact as I have migrated the code to use the new rxjs operators. I am still getting the following errors. Dont know the reason why

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject.d.ts:1:15
    TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/BehaviorSubject'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:1:15
    TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/rxjs/Observer.d.ts:1:15
    TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observer'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/rxjs/Operator.d.ts:1:15
    TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Operator'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts:1:15
    TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subject'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.d.ts:1:15
    TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subscription'.
```

Comment: Have you accidentally left any `import` statements in your code referencing the `rxjs-compat` package?

Comment: Try `npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save`

Comment: Hi Peter do i really need to install xjs@6 rxjs-compat@6. Shouldn't the new rxjs 6 work without it

Comment: @Tom Try importing modules like this `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: Have u tried this `npm install --save rxjs@5.5.2`?

Answer (score 134):

None of these answers are correct.
Installing rxjs-compat is just a workaround. All you have to do is correct the imports. Use:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Instead of:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

This last import is supposed to go away when they finally decide to kill rxjs-compat (hopefully very soon)... so heads up! you need to update your code!!

Comment: Can we use the same in package.json etc? I really dont want to execute this on each developers machine

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. Unfortunately, you have to either update all the imports (a regular search and replace will suffice) or use the compat package (which I don't recommend since it's a temporary workaround). The package.json will only ensure the version of the packages you're using, what you do with them is in the code.

Comment: This answer needs to be upvoted more because it is the best answer

Comment: Also see https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration#import-paths for a list of all imports you might have to change

Comment: Even angular university can get this wrong: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/

Comment: We tried using the `rxjs-compat` and that was a mess and doesn't really set you up to upgrade in the future. If you update the imports, have the correct version in your package.json and use git/github to share the code with fellow developers, if you run `npm i` it should just work on every machine afterwards.

Comment: This worked for me.  Saved me so much time that I should buy this fine gentleman dinner from the finest of establishments.

Answer (score 110):

This will solve the issue:

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

[See this GitHub issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-handsontable/issues/505)

**Edit** : as per 10th October 2019 ,you can use below syntax as the earlier or the above one was a workaround.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Reference doc: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#dropping-the-compatibility-layer

Comment: Do I need to add that as a dependency in the package.json file. I have upgraded all the rxjs operators in the application to use new rxjs 6 functionality. Unfortunately the d.ts files under the observable are referring to rxjs-compat. for e.g export * from 'rxjs-compat/observable/bindNodeCallback';.

Comment: @Tom no need to add the dependency manually as cli does for you.So your package.json will have  "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3" as an entry under "dependencies" node.

Comment: this shouldn't be the correct answer... using the rxjs-compat is just a temporary solution they created to keep using old imports safely in the new version... what you should do is update your imports. See my answer below 

Answer (score 11):

As, Jandro Rojas, already said, installing rxjs-compat dependency it's only a temporary walkaround. In the future, you still need to fix that. The best solution is to use an Angular update guide 
https://update.angular.io/ because of some mistakes can be fixed automatically.

From my experience with errors "Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'", "Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat'" and etc.

- You should fix all the imports. From:

```html
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
```

To:

```html
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
```

- If you use RxJS observables classes or etc, you need to update your
  code. Use this guide -> [RxJS v5.x to v6 Update Guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)
- Check carefully your dependencies, it should be updated too to use
  the newest RxJs. In my case "ngx-bootstrap" was outdated.

Answer (score 7):

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

and run the server again with `ng serve`

This works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Just open command prompt & add below command in to your root folder.

```
npm i rxjs-compat
```

Hope it's working ..

Answer (score 3):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

this will be enough, there's no need for other imports

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me just by replacing `'rxjs/Subscription'` with `'rxjs'`

Answer (score 3):

1. install rxjs if not installed:

   npm install --save rxjs-compat

2-import observable:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
```

instead of:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/dist/types";
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the rxjs and rxjs-compat of the version 6.3.2 worked for me.

```
npm install rxjs@6.3.2 --save  &&  npm install rxjs-compat@6.3.2 --save
```

Answer (score 1):

- ] node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'

I have got same above error, to resolve the issue enter this command in you CLI:

- **npm install --save rxjs-compat**

Then after import: 
**import { Observable } from 'rxjs';**

Answer (score 1):

Those who have this error while creating a salesforce project in VSCode, should ensure that the command - `npm install rxjs@6.3.2 --save  &&  npm install rxjs-compat@6.3.2 --save`

are installed in - `C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\client\node_modules directory`

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat

import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
```

*run server ng serve
worked for Me*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like rxjs-compat is missing. just do

```
npm i rxjs-compat 

npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall @ngrx/store

npm install @ngrx/store@5.2.0

npm install --save rxjs-compat

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

in package.json add dependency
"rxjs": "^6.5.4"
then yarn install

or yarn add rxjs@^6.5.4

Answer (score 0):

https://rxjs.dev/guide/installation

install both the below packages

```
npm install rxjs-compat
npm install @reactivex/rxjs
```

Answer (score -1):

```
npm i rxjs-compat
```

It's working for me.

Answer (score -1):

I am using **Angular 10**,this method works for me.

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

you should import **observable** this way:-

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```