# Why does rjxjs-compact error persist after correct the import

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I was trying to implement phone call functionality following this [tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number).
I got an error along the lines of 'ionic-native/core' missing.
I read a solution that suggested I install ionic  native/core@4, which I did but now the app is riddled with compilation errors.

The first error is in relation to

> rxjs-compat/observable Module not found.

I have followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388927/cannot-find-module-rxjs-compat-observable) , most errors were resolved by adding the import to the file outlined in the error thrown :

From:
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

To:
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

but the error is still been thrown but no reference to where the import is been called, so I don't know how to resolve:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'rxjs-compat/observable/fromEvent' in
> '...Project Directory../node_modules/rxjs/observable'
> Manual/node_modules/rxjs/observable'

node_modules/rxjs:

```
"use strict";
function __export(m) {
    for (var p in m) if (!exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) exports[p] = m[p];
}
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
__export(require("rxjs-compat/Observable"));
```

My question how do I resolve this error if the solution is to add the import to the file where the import called is not specified in the error?